# Connector Odoo-channable

Tags: odoo, e-commerce

I'm looking for an Odoo connector with chanable, which allows me to load the feed, download the orders to Odoo and do all the basic tasks that a connector should do, does anyone know of one that works well? Thank you

I can't find an odo connector with channable that runs in my own odoo, I'm looking for a single payment module and not an external service